# How to run an old cakephp project in localhost?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have been assigned a new project with Old Cakephp to do some changes on it, i don't know how to run the project on my Xammp/Wamp with Cakephp 4.

Comment: Which version? Describe your problems. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: cakephp version 2.6.8 and php version 5.6

Comment: You can't run that project "on CakePHP 4". You can *upgrade* it to CakePHP 4, but that's a major task. There's tons of Q&A about what's involved in that. And you may or may not be able to run what you have with any PHP newer than 5.6.

Comment: `composer install` and run. No extra instruction not required(only need db connection sedup)

Comment: @RiTeSh can you explain more?

Comment: Can you share, what's going wrong @JigarRathod